# How to get dead tuples of each database in postgres server with database name?

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a postgres query that can display database name in one column and dead tuples in another column. I tried query using pg_stat_user_tables and pg_class but I didn't find a way of getting dead tuple with database name.

Comment: The issue is that most of the system catalog information is restricted to the database you are connected to.  So in order to aggregate across databases you would have to connect to each database in turn and gather the appropriate stats and store them somewhere for a final query that would produce your desired output.

Comment: Is there a way to added database name in pg_class query?

Comment: `pg_class` does not have a database field as the values are only for those objects in the current database. If you want the current database then from here [System Info Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-info.html) `current_database()`.